# How to mod rewrite in .htaccess a subdirectory with parameter and access via php?

Tags: .htaccess, web, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How to mod-rewrite `domain.com/subdir/file.php?param=foo` to `domain.com/subdir/file/foo` and access variable via `$_GET['param']` in the .htaccess file?

I tried this in the .htaccess in the subdirectory itself

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdir/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ file.php?param=$1 [QSA,L]
```

but php doesn't find `$_GET['param']`.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: php does not find `$_GET['param']`

Comment: Is `file.php` located in `/subdir/` ? what URL are you going to?

Comment: yes `file.php` is in `/subdir/`

Comment: I would like to use it for a email verification. `https://example.com/singup/activate.php?key=123ABC`to `https://example.com/signup/activate/123ABC`

Comment: I think `Multiviews` are conflicting with your RewriteRule. Try Adding the following line to your htaccess to disable it. `Options -Multiviews` .

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help

Comment: maybe there is an interference with the `.htaccess` form parent directory. There is this part: ´RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f`
`RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]`

Comment: Your webserver is reading `/subdir/.htaccess` to serve all subdir URLs.

Comment: What happens when you go to `/subdir/file/foobar` ? Do you get to the `/subdir/file.php` page?